# How can i replace any word but one in a string using C# regex?

Tags: c#, regex, match

Given a string like this:
`Fixing this [HFW] takes alot of [HFW] time [HFW]`

should be this:
`[CW] [CW] [HFW] [CW] [CW] [CW] [HFW] [CW] [HFW]`

I need to replace any word with `[CW]` except the tags `[HFW]`.
I've been trying this alot, the best i got is:

```
regex = new Regex(@"[^(\[HFW\])_]+");
cleanText = regex.Replace(cleanText, " [CW] ");
```

Which almost works, but i get the first capital F left out, being a part of `[HFW]` tag. I mean, it won't take `[HFW]` as a group.

Thank you

Comment: Why regex?  Isn't this easier to do by tokenizing the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got one which is a bit... cranky? But it does the trick for your sample string:

```
(?<!\[|F|\[F)\w+(?!W|\]|W\]\])
```

The issue with `[^...]` is that it doesn't look at the order of the characters `\[`, `H`, `F`, `W` or `\]`.

There's probably a more elegant one than this and I'm still trying to look for it.

Another possible one:

```
\w+(?=\s)|(?<=\s)\w+
```

Comment: That's not working, it's replacing every character with [CW] except [HFW]. I need to replace every whole word.

Comment: @user569605 It's replacing every whole word, I already tested it [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/vI2qA1). Your current pattern replaces series of words by a single `[CW]`. Is that what you actually want?

Comment: I found another expression: `\w+(?=\s)|(?<=\s)\w+`. Maybe that one is better at your code? I'm still confused that C# is taking every character :(

Comment: It was my mistake, it takes the whole word. Thank you alot :)

Comment: @user569605 Awesome then! :)